# Validating unique field with HABTM join table

Tags: validation, cakephp, model

I'm struggling to work out how to validate a field in Model A that should be unique when combined with a field from Model B.

Here's an example to clarify my question:

```
Page hasMany SitesPage
SitesPage belongsTo Page, belongsTo Site
```

Page has a slug field which should be unique across a site. Pages can be attached to any site.

```
Page.id
Page.slug

SitesPage.id
SitesPage.site_id
SitesPage.page_id
```

I have a checkUniqueSlug() custom validation method in my Page model but can't validate the slug is unique to the site as the site_id is stored in SitesPage which isn't available in the Page model validate method ($this->data only contains Page model data).

I can't do the validation in the SitesPage model as SitesPage doesn't have a slug field and I can't see the Page post is SitesPage.

**How do I create a custom validation to check the slug is unique to the site?**

One solution is to move the slug into the SitesPage model but we need all shared pages to have the same slug. i.e. A shared "About Us" page must have an "about_us" slug irrespective of which site the page is attached to.

Another solution is to perform the validation in the controller before I save which would work but that feels wrong as the validation should be done in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there have been no answers and someone else might be looking for help, here's how I ended up with a solution:

As the controller is the only place where both model data is present in the data array, the  call to validate has to be done there.

I offloaded the validation code to the model and called it with the following:

```
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {

  if ($this->Model->specialMultiModelValidate($this->request->data) && $this->Model->save($this->request->data)) {

    // model has validated and saved

  }
  else {

     // model has failed to validate and save

  }

}
```

Hope someone finds this useful.